# Why didn't Voltron's pilots' suits match the colors of their lions?

Tags: lion-force-voltron

In the *Lion Force Voltron* series from the 1980s, the original pilots' suit colors and the colors of the lions were basically the same, yet each pilot did not operate the lion of the matching color:

- Keith wore a red suit but piloted the black lion.
- Lance wore a blue suit but piloted the red lion.
- Sven wore a black suit but piloted the blue lion.

Only Pidge (green) and Hunk (yellow/orange) wore suits that corresponded to their lions' colors.

Why were the colors mismatched?  I'm interested in either in-universe or out-of-universe explanations. (Were the colors also always mismatched in the original *Beast King GoLion* series?)